# Issue with getting a ModalPopUp to display a populated textbox correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, textbox, modalpopupextender

My site has descriptions of the products we sell and I am currently trying to get those descriptions to pop up inside a modal popupextender. I can get them to popup with a textbox where I have enabled="false" so that it can't be edited, but it shows all the tags along with the text such as the `<p>`, `<li>`, etc. Is there a different control I can use inside of my modal that will show my text better?

```
 <!-- Descriptions -->
 <asp:TabPanel ID="tab2"  runat="server" HeaderText="Descriptions">
 <HeaderTemplate>Descriptions</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul class="info">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvDescriptions" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsMarketingDescriptions" DataKeyNames="MarketingID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ViewDescriptionButton" runat="server"><%#Eval("MarketingTitle")%></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteDescriptionButton" runat="server" Style="float:right;" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="../../images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this description?')" />
                <asp:Panel ID="ViewDescriptionPanel" runat="server">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelDescriptionButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../images/exit.png" AlternateText="" Style="float:right;"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Description" runat="server" width="100px" height="100px" Enabled="false" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("MarketingData") %>'/>
                </asp:Panel> 
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ViewDescriptionModal" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" PopupControlID="ViewDescriptionPanel" TargetControlID="ViewDescriptionButton" CancelControlID="CancelDescriptionButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>              
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
```

Here's an example of the <%# Eval("MarketingData")%>:
      `<p>If you are currently trading options on futures or are interested in exploring them further, check out this newly updated trading guide, featuring 25 commonly used options strategies, including butterflies, straddles, strangles, backspreads and conversions. Each strategy includes an illustration demonstrating the effect of time decay on the total option premium involved in the position.</p><p>Options on futures rank among the most versatile risk management tools, and are offered on most CME Group products. Whether you trade options for purposes of hedging or speculating, you can limit your risk to the amount you paid up-front for the option while maintaining your exposure to beneficial price movements.</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text wont be editable, why don't you use a asp:label instead?

Does the MarketingData field include html tags? Please provide an example of the value for MarketingData.

**Edit:**
If you know wich tags can be present on your text, you can simply create a property on the class that hold the propoerty called MarketingData, like this:

```
public string EditedMarketingData
{
    get {return MarketingData.Replace("<p>","").Replace("</p>","").Replace("<li>","");}
}
```

And then change the binding in your text box as:

```
Text='<%# Eval("EditedMarketingData") %>'
```

The replacing is kind of ugly, hope you can get that to look better ;)

Comment: Yes they include html tags. I don't know why but that's the way they have been put in the database, it probably makes it easier for one of our other sites. Check edits above.

Comment: The other option you have is to edit the text on the binding event, but i would prefer to use a specific purpose property since you could need it in other point of your app.

Comment: I went ahead and took the first piece of advice you had to offer, which was using a label. I added some stuff to the CSS and it is working just the way I wanted it to before. The label is a lot easier than trying to make a textbox non-editable. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

I think a Literal would be the most appropriate control for this type of content, as it will preserve the HTML in the content. You could probably also use a Label.

If you would prefer to stick with a TextBox though, I would try setting the ReadOnly property to false (instead of Enabled). If you want to achieve the disabled.

Comment: I don't know why I was using a textbox, I just couldn't think of anything better at the time. Thanks for the cyberstalk again @James! :)

Comment: Oh I tried using a literal earlier, but I'm not familiar with it so I used a label :)

Comment: If it displays correctly, that's all that matters. The only difference is that a label wraps the content in a SPAN.